# How to set the current working directory in the Python sh module?

Tags: python

Is there a way to set the current working directory within a call to the Python [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module?

I'd like to be able to execute a command --- and only the command --- in a different directory than the one I'm currently in. Something along the lines of:

```
import sh
foo = sh.ls(_current_directory="/tmp")
```

woudl be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`_cwd` parameter](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/special_arguments.html#special-keyword-arguments) to set the current working directory on a per-command basis:

```
import sh
print(sh.ls(_cwd='/tmp'))
```

This works for any command, not just `sh.ls`.